# Shoppingcart with a drop-down list with a pre-selected option

Tags: php, html, mysql

What I have now

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title> Simple PHP Mysql Shopping Cart</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">LS-Net Shopping Cart</h3><br />  
                <?php  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC";  
                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                {  
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                     {  
                ?>  
                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">  
                          <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                               <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                               <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>  
                               <h4 class="text-danger">DKK <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>  
                               <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />  
                               <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <?php  
                     }  
                }  
                ?>  
                <div style="clear:both"></div>  
                <br />  
                <h3>Order Details</h3>  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="40%">Item Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Quantity</th>  
                               <th width="20%">Price</th>  
                               <th width="15%">Total</th>  
                               <th width="5%">Action</th>  
                          </tr>  



                          <?php   
                          if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
                          {  
                               $total = 0;  
                               foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
                               {  
                          ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>  
                               <td>DKK <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></td>  
                               <td>DKK <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2); ?></td>  
                               <td><a href="index.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a></td>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                                    $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);  
                               }  
                          ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>  
                               <td align="right">DKK <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>  
                               <td></td>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
</html>
```

---

```
<?php  
 session_start();  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', "test"); 
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$connect->set_charset("utf8");

 if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
 {  
      if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
      {  
           $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");  
           if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))  
           {  
                $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);  
                $item_array = array(  
                     'item_id'               =>     $_GET["id"],  
                     'item_name'               =>     $_POST["hidden_name"],  
                     'item_price'          =>     $_POST["hidden_price"],  
                     'item_quantity'          =>     $_POST["quantity"]  
                );  
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';  
                echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $item_array = array(  
                'item_id'               =>     $_GET["id"],  
                'item_name'               =>     $_POST["hidden_name"],  
                'item_price'          =>     $_POST["hidden_price"],  
                'item_quantity'          =>     $_POST["quantity"]  
           );  
           $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;  
      }  
 } 
 if(isset($_GET["action"]))  
 {  
      if($_GET["action"] == "delete")  
      {  
           foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
           {  
                if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])  
                {  
                     unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);  
                     echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';  
                     echo '<script>window.location="index.php"</script>';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

I'm trying to combine all 3 of my boxes into one, so there's only one box showing, and I guess that should be simple enough.

But how do I make a Dropdown list in between the `<h4>` and price? 
Example; when you pick "lille mål" it changes the price beneath, to "lille måls" price. 
The images are irrelevant in order to change when you pick something from the dropdown.
You can take a look at the attached image, for you to visualize it.

Thanks. :-)

Comment: Can you add your final/rendered HTML ? So we'll be able to create a working snippet.

Comment: I think you have to be more specific, i'm a beginner and I don't know what you mean.. sorry

Comment: I mean in your first code extract, there are numerous `<?php /* php code */ ?>`. Can you copy/paste the rendered HTML from your internet browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
Like this? 


<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <title>LS-net Cart</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Simple PHP Mysql Shopping Cart</h3><br />  

                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=1">  
                          <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                               <img src="1.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                               <h4 class="text-info">Fodboldmål</h4>  
                               <h4 class="text-danger">DKK 595.00</h4>  
                               <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="Fodboldmål" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="595.00" />  
                               <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  

                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=2">  
                          <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                               <img src="2.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                               <h4 class="text-info">Træning</h4>  
                               <h4 class="text-danger">DKK 375.00</h4>  
                               <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="Træning" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="375.00" />  
                               <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  

                <div class="col-md-4">  
                     <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=3">  
                          <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                               <img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                               <h4 class="text-info">Lille mål</h4>  
                               <h4 class="text-danger">DKK 299.00</h4>  
                               <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="Lille mål" />  
                               <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="299.00" />  
                               <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  

                <div style="clear:both"></div>  
                <br />  
                <h3>Order Details</h3>  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="40%">Item Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Quantity</th>  
                               <th width="20%">Price</th>  
                               <th width="15%">Total</th>  
                               <th width="5%">Action</th>  
                          </tr>  




                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
           <br />  
      </body>  
 </html>
```